# Mac with two internal drives: how can I make moving the default drag operation?

Tags: macos, mac

I have two internal drives in my Mac, an SSD and an HDD. Since parts of my home directory are symlinked to the HDD, I frequently run into an issue where dragging a file into a different folder causes it to be copied instead of moved. (Because, for example, the Documents folder is technically on a separate drive than my Desktop folder, the former being on the HDD instead of the SSD.)

Is there a way to, for drag operations between those two drives specifically, make Move the default action rather than Copy? Having to remember to hold Command is kind of annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with bash and the terminal, you can use the `mv` command. For example:

```
mv ~/Documents/test.txt /Volumes/Drive/Documents/
```

`mv` the command, `~/Documents/test.txt` the source (home dir/Documents/test.txt) and lastly `/Volumes/Drive/Documents/` the destination.

Im not sure if Mac OS has a feature to set cut or move as a default. I have a mac and I dislike the copy drag and drop as well so I just use the terminal. Hope this helps sum.